# Will a key light, a back light, and white reflector as fill achieve a white background for portrait photography?

Tags: product-photography, fashion

Good evening experts. I have a Nikon D5200 with 50mm f/1.8 lens.  Shooting fashion photography, and trying to get a white background.  Would 3 point lighting with a white reflector as fill give me a good result ?

Comment: I want to comment that your title is a diferent situation as the one you describe on the post.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, the long answer is depends.

### The background

- Are you shooting full body? It is a little more difficult to make a smooth background.
- Do you have enough space between your background to the subject? If you have considerable space you can put more power to the background light or use a big difused light.
- Does the background light has enough power and amplitude to fill the background?
- Do you have enough space between the background and the background flash to have an even ilumination? You can use one light in some cases.
- Does the main light spills some light on the background? It can help to smooth the background. The same as the next question.
- Is your studio painted in white? This last two options helps for a high key portrait.

### Main subject

- Is the white reflector big enough?
- Can you put the reflector it verey close to the subject? Probably remove it later in post pro.
- Is the main light big enough, in the right angle and distance to spill light to the reflector?
- Can you use aditional white boards to fill the subject?
- Are you limited to use a white reflector? or Can you use a silver one?
- How much shadow do you want on your subject?

**My recomendations**

- Play with your lights, have fun and make tests considering all this variables: Difussion, distances, power, ambient.
- You can use a second flash as a background flash and a rim light for example.
- Use swich between one or two flashes for the background.
- Bounce the flashes all over a small white room, or make a light tent for a full body.
- Make a dramatic shadow with a single main light but white background.
- Use some natural ambient light.
- Again, play and have fun.

Comment: Yes i have a white l shape pvc background with aprox a 2 feet distance between the subject n backwall what should I do..?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Virtual Lighting Studio](http://www.zvork.fr/vls/)** to simulate the result of your lighting setup. There are lots of other applications which do the same think. I use **[set.a.light 3D STUDIO](https://www.elixxier.com/en/products/setalight3d.php)**

good shooting.